# Want to print 3rd highest salary and name along with it in SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, subquery

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Employees  
(  
     Id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),  
     FirstName varchar(50),  
     LastName varchar(20),  
     Location varchar(20),  
     Gender varchar(50),  
     Salary int,
     Age int
)  

INSERT INTO tbl_Employees VALUES ('Chittaranjan', 'Swain','Odisha', 'Male', 80000, 23)  
INSERT INTO tbl_Employees VALUES ('Chandin', 'Swain', 'Pune','Female', 76000, 34)  
INSERT INTO tbl_Employees VALUES ('Mitu', 'Pradhan','Delhi', 'Male', 55000, 20)  
INSERT INTO tbl_Employees VALUES ('Jeni', 'Swain','Chennai', 'Female', 76000, 34)  
INSERT INTO tbl_Employees VALUES ('Adyashree', 'Swain','UK', 'Female', 49000, 36)  
INSERT INTO tbl_Employees VALUES ('Ram', 'Kumar','US', 'Male', 39000, 45)  
INSERT INTO tbl_Employees VALUES ('Jitendra', 'Gouad','Hydrabad', 'Male', 35000, 35)  
INSERT INTO tbl_Employees VALUES ('Dibas', 'Hembram','Bangalore', 'Male', 55000, 56)
```

I want to find out the 3rd highest salary and wants to print it. But along with that, i also want to print the name of that person

```
SELECT 
    MIN(Salary) AS minimum
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 Salary
     FROM tbl_Employees
     ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS a
```

I have been able to find out the 3rd highest salary only till now, but i want name of that particular person with it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DENSE_RANK() function serialize the position without a GAP. If two values in same position then third value position after this to value will 2. But if use RANK() function it'll 3. so it'll create a gap.

```
-- SQL Server
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
           , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) sl_no
      FROM tbl_Employees) t
WHERE t.sl_no = 3
```

Please find this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25e3f32ddb04691d99518251f5b074c7

Answer (score 2):

`OFFSET` seems to be what you want here:

```sql
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       Salary
FROM dbo.tbl_Employees E
ORDER BY Salary DESC
OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: it has duplicate values.

Comment: Not in your sample data, @ChitranshMathur . And you don't say you want multiple rows on your question. If that's what you want, you need to ask a new question now.

Comment: @ChitranshMathur You can always add a `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates, that's the only difference I see in your original query that might account for that.

Answer (score 1):

The window function `row_number() over()` should do the trick

Note:  Use `dense_rank()` if you want to see ties.

```
Select *
 From  (
         Select *
               ,RN = row_number() over (order by salary desc)
             From tbl_Employees  
       ) A
 Where RN = 3
```

Comment: Cappellatti it has duplicate values.

Comment: @ChitranshMathur As I mentioned... use dense_rank() instead of row_number()